# Страницы не закрываются от индексации

Tags: оптимизация, seo, индексация, robots.txt

Закрыл от индексации несколько URL, добавив в `robots.txt` следующие строки

```
Disallow: /warranty/
Disallow: /payment/
Disallow: /patent/
```

Но screaming frog и яндекс вебмастер по-прежнему утверждают, что на этих страницах отсутствует `description`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из [документации](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/intro?hl=ru) Google:

> Файл robots.txt **не** предназначен для того, чтобы запрещать показ ваших материалов в результатах поиска Google

Из [документации](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.html) Яндекса:

> Ограниченные в robots.txt страницы **могут** участвовать в поиске Яндекса.

Исходя из этого, robots.txt - просто рекомендация, а не прямой запрет для ботов

Плюсом - сторонние сервисы аналитики/диагностики сайтов могут проверять его с задержкой/кэшировать/етц. Проще всего эти моменты уточнить у поддержки конкретного сервиса